# What is the difference between 3years, 4 years, and 5years PhDs?

Tags: phd

My question excludes the USA and similar systems (e.g. Canada, Singapore, South Korea, China, etc), and the UK and similar systems (e.g. Australia, New Zealand, South Africa, India, etc).

I found that:

1. Some countries offer 3years PhDs, e.g., Germany, Austria, etc.
2. Some countries offer 4years PhDs, e.g., Russia, Poland, Estonia, etc.
3. Some countries offer 5years PhDs, e.g., Israel.

What is the basic difference?

Comment: The basic difference is the amount of time you have available, or at least, funded. Even than, if you exceed the limit there is often a way to get some extra funding. So it is more a difference in guaranteed funding than in actual funding. Other than that, you have a large range of countries, so there are obviously lots and lots of other differences.

Comment: The number of years refers only to the number of years you get funded. In practice, in my experience in many countries people almost always take a bit longer than the length of the contract, i.e. 3 year PhDs often take 4 years, whereas 4 year PhDs often take 5. If your supervisor or anyone else has funding, they can extend your contract. Otherwise, you might need to finish while living on unemployment benefits.